# What's wrong with my sub-theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I wanted to make some customizations to the "Seven" administration theme, so I started by installing the "Blossom" sub theme of Seven found here: http://drupal.org/project/blossom-admin .

This worked fine.  So then I copied /sites/all/themes/blossom-admin and named it /sites/all/themes/myadmin

In the .info file for myamin, I changed

```
name = Blossom
description = Drupal Gardens administration theme.
```

to

```
name = myadmin
destription = my description of this theme
```

And just to be safe, I also renamed any files that had the "blossom" name to "myadmin" in both the .info file and to the actual files themselves.  (Like renamed blossom.css to myadmin.css)

Now when I go to the Drupal admin and select myadmin as the administration theme, it works, but includes my main navigation and a footer region content at the top of the theme.  Does anyone know why this would happen to a straight copy of the blossom theme which worked fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you rename all the functions in the template.php file as well? These need to start with your theme name ;-)

Comment: I did that now, but I'm still getting other problems, like this error showing up everywhere: _Notice: Undefined variable: breadcrumb in include()_ .   And when I make a change to the style sheet, it doesn't affect the appearance.

Comment: I think I'm going to start over fresh, copying the original "Seven" theme and going off that one. Is copying and renaming the template.php file a requirement when making a sub-theme? I was under the impression that I only need to keep the files that I need to change, which in my case are just the .css files and of course the .info files.

Comment: yes, otherwise the theme overrides are not applied to that theme. Make sure you install the devel module and enable that the theme is being rebuilt for every call - cleares caches so changes to the theme are seen instantly.